# How to fix this indexing error?

Tags: catalog, reindex, magento2.2.4, catalog-product-price-index

When I am running `indexer:reindex` command, I am getting this error.

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1448-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_temp` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_replica`.* FROM `catalog_product_index_price_replica` WHERE (entity_id IN('5472', '5842', '5848', '5467', '5468', '5471', '5848', '5467', '5468', '5851', '5855', '5467', '5471', '5472', '5848', '5467', '5468', '5851', '5855', '5466', '5467', '5468', '1603', '1604', '1605', '1606', '1607', '5472', '5842', '5467', '5468', '5467', '5468', '6214', '6215', '6216', '6217', '1448', '1449', '1450', '1451', '1452', '5696', '5697', '5698', '5699', '5700'))

I tried to disable this product and tried again the command, Again I am getting another set of products as this.

I tried `php bin/magento index:reset` command, It invalidates the index, and when I am running `php bin/magento indexer: reindex` it will keep running but not complete.

Any suggestion or help to fix this issue?

Comment: as a trial suggestion, i would recommend you to take the table and DB back up and post that truncate the table 'catalog_product_index_price_replica' once, and then please run the commands... hopefully with the index run it will generate the table values else you have to go out for some further debug to fix it in other ways....bdw for longrun you have to check for some solution but once correctly generated I think the issue will not reoccur so give a try

Comment: @BibhuAsish thanks i will try this